# how to print three maps together in three different columns on console? c++

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have three `map<string,int>` instances. All three contain student names and and their marks. The first map contains computer students, second one contains medical students and the third one contains commerce students. I know I have to use `<iomanip>`library and `setw`. What I don't get is how do I iterate through all three at the same time to print them together? Can anyone help? I want it to be printed on the console as:

```
COMPUTER MEDICAL COMMERCE
joey 45 ed 20 harold 50
malisa 36 jane 60 aron 70
emily 60 judy 70 barney 45
```

So far what I have but this just prints one map after the other

```
  map<string,int> ::const_iterator it;
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<setw(36)<<"COMPUTER STUDENTS"<<endl;
  for( it = one.begin(); it != one.end(); ++it)
  {
    cout <<setw(20)<<it->first;
    cout <<setw(5)<<it->second<<endl;
  }
  cout<<setw(36)<<"MEDICAL STUDENTS"<<endl;
  for( it = two.begin(); it != two.end(); ++it)
  {
    cout <<setw(20)<<it->first;
    cout <<setw(5)<<it->second<<endl;
  }
  cout<<setw(36)<<"COMMERCE STUDENTS"<<endl;
  for(it = three.begin(); it != three.end(); ++it)
  {
    cout <<setw(20)<<it->first;
    cout <<setw(5)<< it->second<<endl;
  }`
```

Comment: Now change that to a single `for` loop where you use iterators to all 3 maps. You'll want to ensure prior to the `for` loop that the sizes of all 3 are the same.

Comment: Do all of your maps have the same size?

Comment: @NathanOliver yes same size

Comment: @Praetorian can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using range loop for first map and iterators for next 2 maps:

```
 std::map<string,int> one, two, three;
  //You inserted records to all three maps
   std::map<string,int>::iterator it2 = two.begin();
   std::map<string,int>::iterator it3 = three.begin();

  if( one.size()== two.size() &&  two.size()==  three.size())
  {
    for( auto &x : one)
    {
        std::cout<<setw(20)<< x.first;
        std::cout<<setw(5)<< x.second;
        std::cout<<setw(20)<<it2->first;
        std::cout<<setw(5)<< it2->second;
        std::cout<<setw(20)<<it3->first;
        std::cout<<setw(5)<< it3->second;
        ++it2;
        ++it3;
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the sizes are guaranteed to be equal (per your comment), you can use one loop and three iterators something similar to the following. Please note that `cout` statements should be arranged based on your needs. This is just to show an example of **how to iterate three sets of equal size in a single loop**:

```
map<string,int> ::const_iterator it1, it2, it3;

it1=one.begin();
it2=two.begin();
it3=three.begin();

while(it1!=one.end())
{
    cout<<it1->first<<" ";  // You should format them based on your need
    cout<<it1->second<<" "; // This is just an example.
    cout<<it2->first<<" ";
    cout<<it2->second<<" ";
    cout<<it3->first<<" ";
    cout<<it3->second<<" ";
    it1++; it2++; it3++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Have an idea with the equal-sized assumption is not required.
Put the contents of the three maps into one common vector:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 map<int, int> m;
 m[1] = 1;
 m[2] = 2;
 map<int, int> n;
 n[3] = 3;
 n[4] = 4;
vector<pair<int, int> > v;
copy(m.begin(), m.end(), back_inserter(v));
copy(n.begin(), n.end(), back_inserter(v));
for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
cout << v[i].first << " : " << v[i].second << endl;
}
```

This consume extra memory. But good point is you can do whatever you want with these data by any algorithm in vector (such as sorting). I don't know why you need three maps. My preference is to have an extra flag for the data and have them in one map.